# doing the no-vowels cs50 problem and ran into an error with strcat

Tags: arrays, c, cs50, strcat

When running my program:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Give me a word: " );
    int j = strlen(word);
    int i;
    char new[j + 1];

    new[0] = '\0';
    
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'e')
        {
            strcat(new, "3");
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'i')
        {
            strcat(new, "1");
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            strcat(new, "6");
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'o')
        {
            strcat(new, "0");
        }
        else
        {
            char p = word[i];
            strcat(new, p);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", new);
}
```

I get the error:

```
no-vowels-test.c:39:25: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
            strcat(new, word[i]);
                        ^~~~~~~
                        &
/usr/include/string.h:149:70: note: passing argument to parameter '__src' here
extern char *strcat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
```

My goal here is to make the last `else` statement append the current letter in the array of `word[i]` into the variable `new[]` to spell out a new word where every vowel is replaced by a number, the numbers I have no problem with. But the last `else` statement seems to have a problem and I cant figure out why.

Comment: The `char p = word[i]; strcat(new, p);` needs a complete C string not a single character.

Comment: Your example also ignores the vowel 'u'. Do you only replace lower case vowels, or must you also replace upper case vowels?

Comment: This could be a string-based look-up table: `"eiao"` and `"3160"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `strcat` must be a C string, ie: an array of `char` terminated with a null byte, not a single `char` such as `p`.

You can fix this problem with `strncat`: replace `strcat(new, p);` and the previous line with:

```
    strncat(new, &word[i], 1);
```

This concatenates at most 1 `char` from the string starting at `word[i]`.

Another approach would set the bytes in `new` directly:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Give me a word: " );
    int i;
    int j = strlen(word);
    char new[j + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'e')
        {
            new[i] = '3';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'i')
        {
            new[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            new[i] = '6';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'o')
        {
            new[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            new[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    new[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", new);
}
```

Comment: @ikegami: Indeed `j` is fully redundant. I initially through `j` would only get incremented for vowels... answer amended and simplified.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great. Now im having a new problem, everything i input the word "coordination" it works but it adds 2 extra letters to the end, theyre different each time. any clue why this is?

Comment: @Boriscodes: it is unclear what could cause the new problem. You might want to as a new question with the actual code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

To use `strcat`, you would need to provide a pointer to a NUL-terminated string.

```c
char s[ 2 ] = { word[ i ], 0 };
strcat( new, s );
```

But you don't need `strcat` to add a single character. Especially since you already know the position at which to write the character. All you need is `new[ i ] = c;`. Just don't forget to terminate your string with a NUL once you're done.

Comment: And in fact, they don't need to build up the modified string in a separate local array at all.  They could either modify the provided string in-place, or just print character-by-character as they go, without otherwise storing the modified string at all.  Either one of which would also get them out of relying on a VLA.

Comment: True. _________